# ASP.net MVC5 Deployment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment

I am wondering some point on deploying an Asp.NET MVC5 application to my own server.

1. What if it happens, if i add more attributes in one of my model class or add more model class. What should i do for not losing data.
2. Is there any other options shoul i need to perform other than asp.net mvc4 since i could not find any tutorial about deployin asp.net mvc5 with Identity.
3. What is the best efficient way to change my application view, controller and model on run-time. Can i working on my local PC while using the remote code file and database ?

Regards.

Comment: Are you using EF? I would use everything local when running locally. Code, DB etc.

Comment: Yes i am using EF but i am going deploy an 3rd party server.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time understanding your requirements but for the database part, I would recommend "entity framework migrations". It's made handling model changes locally and remotely.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj554735.aspx

Comment: My question is about losing data.. What should i do, for not losing my data in development. IE if i change my DB scheme and add more fields and tables.. After deploying, i dont want to loose my data .. What should i do? Should i turn off the auto migration?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with entity framework migrations a lot but sometimes if you make big changes, such as Foreign keys or enums, the migrations give a problem. I then started to use a tool from **RedGate.com** called "**Sql Compare**." Works better than Entity migrations - now I don't worry about data changes. Usually this will not lose data, but if it is going to lose data, it will warn you.

Best solution to losing data -make backups.